# Selenium: Data entered in form with multiple tabs disappears sometimes

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a web app with a complicated data entry form that has some tabs that hold entry fields for various configuration items. I am writing a test that enters data in fields on different tabs and then executes a save. As I enter each item, I verify that the data entry control has the text or value I selected before moving on to the next step. I am finding that sometimes, but not always, when I move to another tab, fields on the previous tab lose the data I had entered.

How do I prevent this?

I am using Selenium 2 with WebDriver in java and running tests with Firefox.

I am having trouble with two fields:

One is a simple text entry field
The second is a text entry box with an autocomplete feature

Both fields are the last ones I input data to before switching tabs. None of the other fields that I input data to before switching tabs lose data. Just the ones I interact with right before going to a new tab.

I have tried checking that JQuery is loaded at the end of the method that sends the text to the input fields, but it doesn't seem to help. The method that checks JQuery returns true and the data is still erased sometimes.

This never happens when entering data manually, and it also doesn't happen in another automated test where data is entered on one tab only.

Here is the html for the autocomplete field when text has been entered and there is no pending input that has triggered autocomplete:

```
<div id="s2id_autogen5" class="select2-container select2-container-multi select2">
    <ul class="select2-choices" style="">
        <li class="select2-search-choice">
            <div>
                htm
            </div>
            <a class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1" onclick="return false;" href="#"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="select2-search-field">
            <input class="select2-input" type="text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" style="width: 10px;"></input>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the html source for the simple text entry field:

```
<td class="optionValue option_sr_test_object_url">
    <input id="option_d03e6450-5990-4a31-8e84-5b1af89d2c47_sr_test_object_url" type="text" placeholder="e.g. /path/testobject.html" value="/path/test.html">
    </input>
</td>
```

Comment: It's a bit weird. Perhaps there is something wrong with your (form) code. If so, then the test fulfils its purpose ;)

Comment: It never happens when entering data manually. Or even when entering data using Selenium if I don't switch tabs during the test.

Comment: I see. Sometimes I had JS errors that I only could detect in debugging. I would revise the form code, for just in case. Also, another idea could be some JS name duplication, perhaps causing Selenium's script interact with your form´s code. If it is possible, try to change the function name for the fields' reset in the form.

Comment: I don't have permissions to alter any application source code. I could enter a JIRA against the app for the developers to look into, but they'll just mark it 'WONTDO' or ignore it for a year before anyone bothers to look at it.

Comment: If I insert a Thread.sleep(1000) after I enter the data into the input field and validate that the data is present by retrieving the text I just entered into the field, the data doesn't disappear. I don't know what it is that needs the wait though.

Comment: This last comment and your answer reminded me a similar issue: in a test where several inputs received some text (with sendKeys()), sometimes the text "didn't have time" to enter fully in the corresponding field. The focus moved to the next input, inserting the rest of the previous text and then the text that belonged to this field, concatenating them together. This ended up with wrong values in the first field (truncated value) and the second field (the rest from the first field + the correct value of the second). This is, obviously, a bug in Selenium code. (see next comment)

Comment: I solved it with a kind of workaround: I added some code after calling 'sendKeys()', verifying the inserted value. If it was different (truncated) to the expected one, I deleted it and tried again. A loop of 3 tries to reinsert worked for me. Perhaps you will like this more than the explicit wait.

Comment: Of course, you shouldn't add this workaround to the test code. Just wrap a call to 'sendKeys()' with another method and keep all this workaround stuff separately, because it is likely you will need to add more workarounds due to bugs in Selenium or different browsers ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found something that reliably prevented this happening:

driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandle());

When I execute that line before switching tabs, my previously entered data was not cleared out. I don't know why this works, nor do I remember how I found this as a solution. I kept meaning to update this question with this answer for months, but I kept forgetting to do it.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this for a couple of days, I have a partial solution to my problem:

For the simple text entry box, if I send a Keys.TAB to change focus to the next input field, then the data *USUALLY* doesn't get erased when I switch to another tab on the form. There must be some event that is fired when the focus switches to another field (but not another tab) that doesn't fire when only sendKeys is used to enter the text. However, in some cases, the data still disappears occasionally.

For the input with an autocomplete feature, I had to send a Keys.RETURN or a Keys.TAB to successfully enter the text into the field. With this field, you can either select an option from the autocomplete list or just hit enter or a tab key to input text that doesn't match one of the autocomplate options. After entering the text with Keys.RETURN or Keys.TAB, I needed to change the focus to another field by sending a Keys.TAB. Again, I believe that is some event that needs to fire in order for the data to remain and that event fires only after the focus changes to another input field, but it doesn't happen if I switch tabs.

Checking that JQuery has no active requests doesn't help because in some cases, even when there is no active query, the data still disappears occassionally from one or both of the fields.

I need a really foolproof method that eliminates this problem in all situations. I would prefer not to have to hard code a sleep. Maybe there is a better technique for setting a good wait in a non-coded way? I would love to have a complete solution to my problem because given that this solution isn't foolproof I can't accept this as the answer to the question.